# Riemannian sums approximation: bounds on the argument

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

I'd like to approximate a sum of the form
$
S(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\phi\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ with an integral using Riemannian sums:

$$S(n) \approx n \int_{0}^{1}\phi(x)dx +o(n).$$

My concern is, $k$ in the argument can't be less than $1$. Should I bound the integral between $[0,1]$ or $[1,2]$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $S(n) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \phi(k/n)$?

Comment: yes, you are right.corrected.

Comment: Would you say that the set of k/n from k=1 to n acts more as a representative sample from the interval [0,1] or from the interval [1,2]?

Comment: @DidierPiau:I'm not sure I understood your question. The reason I want to do it is because $k<1$ is not sensible.

Comment: For $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, would you say $\phi(k/n)$ is a value that the function $\phi$ assumes at (i) a point of the interval $[0,1]$, or (ii) a point of the interval $[1,2]$?